# Use Bootstrap input-grp class with custom inputs?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Trying to figure best approach to allowing a groups under one parent container to make use of an ":active" styling. I have my own classes and whatnot for these buttons and I can see I could do so with anchor in btn tags, but not sure with implementing with input tag with my own custom CSS.

```
<div class="alertBtns">
    <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 2 ? -1 : 2)"  value="outstanding swipes">
    <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 3 ? -1 : 3)" value="recent denials">
    <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 4 ? -1 : 4)" value="upcoming dates">
    <input type="button" class="naviaBtn naviaBlue" ng-click="alertShow = (alertShow == 5 ? -1 : 5)" value="account alerts">
</div>
```